# NgOnChanges not firing even after changing value of @Input boolean?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and have seen a various answers on this but could not solve it.I am using Angular 11. Here is my code for it:

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-custom-quill-editor',
      templateUrl: './custom-quill-editor.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./custom-quill-editor.component.css'],
    })
    export class CustomQuillEditorComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
      static textChange() {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
      } 
      quill1: any;
       data: any[] = [new Temp()];
       @Input() flag:boolean=false;
      constructor(private getDataService: GetDataService) {   
      }
    ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges){
    console.log("In ng changes");
 console.log(changes);
let tdelta = {
      ops: this.data,
    };
    var Delta = Quill.import('delta');
    //let editor = new Quill('#editor');  // finding quill editor with id editor
    const delta = new Delta(tdelta);
    //editor.setContents( delta ,'api');
    var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
      modules: {
        toolbar: [
          ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
          ['blockquote'],
          [{ header: 1 }, { header: 2 }],
          [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }],
        ],
      },
      placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
      theme: 'snow', // or 'bubble'
    });
    this.quill1 = quill;
    this.quill1.updateContents(delta, 'api');
    //trigerring these events if text is changed in editor
    quill.on(
      'text-change',
      this.textChange
    );
  }
    }
 ngOnInit(){
    this.getDataService.getJSON().subscribe((fetchedData) => {
      console.log('Fetched data in component');
      console.log(fetchedData);
      console.log("data before assigning it to fetchedData");
      console.log(this.data);
      this.data=fetchedData;
      console.log(this.flag);
      this.flag=!this.flag;
      console.log(this.flag);
      //this.cd.detectChanges();

      console.log("data after assigning it to fetchedData");
      console.log(this.data);
      console.log('Final data array');
      console.log(this.data);

    });
  }
```

In the console I can see that the value of the variable flag changes, but still ngOnChnages is not fired. Is there any alternative method to do this?

Comment: Are you setting the flag value from a parent component? Changing the value in the component class code will not cause the lifecycle hook to fire.

Comment: Oh Thank You  i did not know about this. I am changing the component value in the  component class only.

Comment: But you don’t have any uncommented code in your ngOnChanges in the first place...

Comment: onChanges => A callback method that is invoked immediately after the default change detector has checked data-bound properties if at least one has changed, and before the view and content, children are checked. E.g., in your case is neither a data-bound-property has been changed nor your ngOnChanges logs something.

Comment: @Lonely I have updated the code. Here it shows what action I am trying to perform on ngOnChanges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not use a setter in the input?

```
_private flag
@Input set flag(value){
   this._flag=value;
  ...do something...
}

get flag()
{
   return this._flah
}
```

Comment: That's a kind of beautiful hack, very poor performance, but it would work.

Comment: @Lonely, why do you think that it's a poor performance? -well I don't like the "getter", personally I use in .html `_flag`- I don't read about it, has you a link about the poor performance?

Comment: I guess it will be checked very often than necessary. If this flag takes place within a template for any reason, the performance would be even much worse. I don't know yet if there are related changes in the v^10; maybe they have already improved the performance of "being watched properties." In my experience, I can say: if you have 10+ such checks on each side, the fan will start to get louder.

Comment: @Eliseo Thank You so much this seems to work! But is there any way by which I could fire the setter method from the service. Like when I change the value of this flag in service, this setter method in the component gets fired?

Comment: @SnehanJain, sorry the delay. The setter fire when you change the value of the variable from the parent. I don't know what do you want to say with "I change the value of this flag in service". Generally if you has a service, you can has a "Subject" in your service -you use next to send a value to the subject, and in the component subscribe to this Subject, but it's another way to comunicate with "component" that has no relation with `@Input`